# Update each row with different randomly chosen numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Update Query;

```
Update Table_1
set Value_1 = (select top 1 Rand_Value from Table_2 Order By newid())
```

**This update assigns the same randomly chosen value to each row being updated.**

Is there a way to assign each row being updated with a different value from

Table_2 randomly  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a couple of common table expressions with [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql):

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T1 as table
(
    col1 char(1)
)

DECLARE @T2 as table 
(
    col1 char(1)
)


INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES 
(NULL), (''), (' '), 
(NULL), (''), (' '), 
(NULL), (''), (' '), 
(NULL), (''), (' ')


INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES 
('a'), ('b'), ('c'), 
('d'), ('e'), ('f'), 
('g'), ('h'), ('i')
```

The common table expressions:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  Col1, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM @T1
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  t2.Col1, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) rn
    FROM @T2 t2
    CROSS JOIN @T1 -- Note: the cross join here is to get at least the same amount of records as there are in @T1
)
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE t1
SET col1 = t2.Col1
FROM CTE1 t1
INNER JOIN CTE2 t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/PSZIC85674)

Comment: Funny thing is that with table variables OP's query works, too. The optimizer seems to treat table variables quite different from real ones. Your query on the other hand works fine with both.

Answer (score 2):

Just answering this part of the question(This update assigns the same randomly chosen value to each row being updated.).See below for demo scripts..

I populated 100 rows(sequential integers) both table 1 and table 2 and i executed below script,same as the one you have..

```
Table1 has  1 to 100  
table2 has  20 to 100
```

Now i executed below script,which as per you should update random value for each row

```
update t1
set t1.id=(select top 1 id from #t2 Order By newid())
from #t1 t1
```

Now that you except,each row to be assigned a random value..below is the output i got

```
id 
75
75
75
....
```

The entire table is updated with same value ,but random,this value will be changed everytime you execute the update

why sql server choose to do this.Lets look at execution plan

[image]

The plan is simple nested loops,but SQL choose to use Lazy spool to store the data .

Now if you look closely ,at this plan,there are two more properties Rebind and Rewind.Below are the valued they have

[image]

Rebind means--how many times ,SQL has to go to main table and populate this spool(in this case),since the data has changed

rewind means--How many times SQL server ,choose to use this spool itself,with out touching the main table

SQLserver choose to do 99 rewinds in your case and choose to use the data from lazy spool only,since the data hasn't changed,because of the way you wrote your query

Now if you rewrote your update like below,you will get the desired behaviour you are expecting,since the values are correlated

```
update t1
set t1.id=(select top 1 id from #t2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id Order By newid())
from #t1 t1
```

the above query resulted in below execution plan

[image]

also you can observe the number of rebinds due to correlation

[image]

**Demo Scripts:**

```
drop table if exists #t1;
drop table if exists #t2;

create table #t1
(id int
)

create table #t2
(id int
)


insert into #t1
select top 100 * from numbers
order by n

insert into #t2
select top 100 * from numbers where n>20
order by n

update t1
set t1.id=(select top 1 id from #t2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id Order By newid())
from #t1 t1


select * from #t1
```